# How can I get URL or search query from browsers intent or activity?

Tags: android

Good day

Here's an issue: 
Let's assume, that some user enters url or search query in some browser or even clicks on url in some text editor. After this I suppose some intent with ACTION_WEB_SEARCH flag is created and performed. How can I parse such intent and extract required query or url from it?

I've seen a lot of decisions, but all of them work fine if user shares data. It's not suitable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After this I suppose some intent with ACTION_WEB_SEARCH flag is created and performed.

No.

When the user "clicks on url in some text editor", the typical behavior is for the hosting app to use `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, supplying the URL.

When the user "enters url or search query in some browser", the browser will do whatever the browser wants. Few, if any, browsers will use `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` for this, because `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` is designed to bring up a Web browser to do a search, and a Web browser **already is** a Web browser.

It is conceivable that there are apps that call `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` `Intent`. However, since this is the first I have heard of this action in a number of years, I suspect that it is not all that popular.

> How can I parse such intent and extract required query or url from it?

You are welcome to implement your own activity that supports `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` via an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest. You would retrieve the search terms via `getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)`, as is noted in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm stiil struggling with it. I'm attempting to apply getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY) in onStartCommand() of my Service. This method requires Intent to apply. There is one, as a parameter of onStartCommand(Intent intent), but this one returns just intent of my Service, but I need intent of a browser. How can I get it? Using parseIntent(), getIntent(), parseUri() in onCreate() of my service?

Comment: @zio: "I'm attempting to apply getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY) in onStartCommand() of my Service" -- `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` is an activity action. Nobody, other than perhaps you, will be calling `startService()` with an `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` `Intent`. You are welcome to implement your own activity, as I outlined in my answer, and it can call `startService()`. "I need intent of a browser" -- I do not know what "Intent of a browser" means.

Comment: I realized that it's nearly impossible to achieve my goal. I'll try to use AccessibilityService. Anyway, thank you for your time